# How can I put link into translation label in django

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, href, translation

My issue is, how can I translate label, where is link, inside the label. I am trying but I get only translate for `msgid` not for `msgid`.

site.html

```
<label for="id_data_protection" class="checkbox">
    {% blocktrans %}Lorem <a href="/en/policy" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum</a> lorem ipsum test test {% endblocktrans %}
</label>
```

django.po file

```
#: templates/pages/templates/contact.html:72
msgid ""
"Text <a href=\"/de/datenschutz\" target=\"_blank\">Text</a> "
"TextTextTextTextText"
msgstr ""
"Text <a href=\"/en/policy\" target=\"_blank\">Text Text</a> Text "
"TextTextText TextText"
```

Answer (score 2):

Block trans allows us to say which part should be translated and which need not be.

In your case here is a rough attempt (Untested)

```
{% blocktrans with link="/en/policy" target="_blank" %}
    Lorem <a href="{{ link }}" target="{{ target }}">Lorem ipsum</a> lorem ipsum test test
{% endblocktrans %}
```

That way the translator will skip the link tags (he should) and the link location. Does this help.

Comment: Very helpful thanks! Do you know if there is a way to specify the context like such: `{% trans "Hello" context "account" %}` I could not find it